# URL rewrite to Subfolder (root redirection to subdirectory) .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Using the following rules to serve requests from `/page` subdirectory, with URL rewrite:

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fastload.website$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fastload.website/$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=302]

   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page/$1.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/$1.html [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This will serve `fastload.website/test` from `fastload.website/page/test.html` however, **can't get it to work with trailing slash**: `fastload.website/test/`

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the slash from the `RewriteRule` match.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ page/$1.html [L,NC]
```